# Magento Disable Incoming messages in admin panel

Tags: magento

I have two stores in my site. For those there are separate admin users. I need to disable 'incoming messages' for specific store admin users when they are login to their admin account. I tried from super admin login as in the following;
System->configuration->advanced->Mage_AdminNotification and disable.
But that way did not work.

Can anyone tell me how i can do this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution definitely should work. Maybe you have some custom modules, that show that message?